# Multidimensional brace-enclosed initializer list to multi vector

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

What I want is a possiblility to generate a 5x5 matrix via a brace-enclosed initializer list.
So that it may look later like:

```
enum class MyListType  {
  EMPTY,
  A
};

auto matrix = {
  {MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY},
  {MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A},
  {MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A},
  {MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A},
  {MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY}
};

auto somthing = std::make_shared<Matrix5T>(matrix);
```

For that I have now my Matrix5T class, which works at the moment only for vectors:

```
class Matrix5T
{
public:
  Matrix5T(std::initializer_list<MyListType> matrixIn)
    : matrix(std::make_shared<std::vector<MyListType> >(matrixIn))
  {}

  virtual ~TileMatrix() = default;

private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<MyListType> > matrix;
}
```

So I can do the following:

```
auto matrix = {
  MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY,
  MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A,
  MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A,
  MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A, MyListType::A,
  MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY, MyListType::EMPTY
};

auto somthing = std::make_shared<Matrix5T>(matrix);
```

At the moment I don't find a solution to have a multidimensional vector in my
class initialized by a multidimensional brace-enclosed initializer list.

I tried for example the following, which results in errors:

```
class Matrix5T
{
public:
  Matrix5T(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<MyListType> > matrixIn)
    : matrix(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::vector<MyListType> > >(matrixIn))
  {}

  virtual ~TileMatrix() = default;

private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<MyListType> > > matrix;
}
```

Error is saying that the conversion from the initializer list to the multidimensional vector
does not work:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<MyListType> >’ to ‘const std::vector<std::vector<MyListType> >&’
```

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the range constructor:

```
Matrix5T(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<MyListType>> matrixIn)
    : matrix(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::vector<MyListType>>>(matrixIn.begin(),
                                                                    matrixIn.end())) {}
```